# how to call options/clicked in another file in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

lately i'm just learning tkinter and i want to separate 1 code into 2code but i keep finding erorr

```
    clicked = StringVar()
NameError: name 'StringVar' is not defined
```

or how do we send/catch get to another file after we press the button?

home.py

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from w2 import *
options =[
    "cone",
    "Ball",
    "Cube",
    "Beam"
    ]

clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set(options[0])
Label(win, text="Enter Number", font=('Calibri 10'), bg="yellow", fg="black").place(x=315, y=5)
drop = ttk.Combobox(win, width = 27, textvariable = clicked, value=options)
drop.place(x=265, y=35)
```

w2.py

```
def show(): 
    for i in options:
        if  clicked.get() == 'cone':
                myButton1['state'] = DISABLED
                mylabel = Label(win, text="Volume Cone",bg="yellow", fg="black")
                mylabel.place(x=315, y=125)
                mylabels = Label(win, text="r : ",bg="yellow", fg="black")
                mylabels.place(x=180, y=155)
                mylabelq = Label(win, text="h : ",bg="yellow", fg="black")
                mylabelq.place(x=350, y=155)
                a=Entry(win, width=21)
                a.place(x=200, y=155)
                b=Entry(win, width=22)
                b.place(x=375, y=155)
                myDel2 = Button(win, text="CLEAR VOLUME CONE", command=myDel)
                myDel2.place(x=200, y=178)
                my_label2 = Label(height=89,width=259,image=my_img)
                my_label2.place(x=225, y=238)
                myButton23 = Button(win,width=18, text="calculate", command=cal_cone , bg="red", fg="white")
                myButton23.place(x=375, y=178)
                wlabel = Label(win, text="")
                break
```

this is the full code

https://github.com/IMVERBILIUS/SIMPLE_VOLUME_CONE-BALL_GUI/blob/master/home.py

Comment: Each file that needs to access names defined by Tkinter will need to do its own `import` of Tkinter.

Comment: I highly suggest reading the Python Docs, especially part explaining the [Import System](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=namespace).

Comment: import tkinter as tk  clicked = tk.StringVar()

Comment: Right.  An important concept in Python is that NOTHING is global across modules.  Global variables are local to the file only.  If you want something from another file, you must import it.

Answer (score 0):

- In the `home.py`. Created a function called `show_w2()`
- Add Button and add parameter for `command=show_w2`
- In `w2.py`, add `tkinter` library
- Comment out line 6-8.
- In the `w2.py`. Created a function called `run()`

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
 

win = Tk()
win.geometry('700x400')

options =[
    "cone",
    "Ball",
    "Cube",
    "Beam"
    ]

def show_w2():
    import w2
    w2.run()
    
clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set(options[0])
Label(win, text="Enter Number", font=('Calibri 10'), bg="yellow", fg="black").place(x=315, y=5)

drop = ttk.Combobox(win, width = 27, textvariable=clicked, value=options)
drop.place(x=265, y=35)

show_button = Button(win, text="Show", bg="red", fg="white", command=show_w2)
show_button.place(x=265, y=61)
 
win.mainloop()
```

w2.py.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

 
def show():
     
    #for i in options:
    #if  clicked.get() == 'cone':
    #myButton1['state'] = DISABLED
    mylabel = Label( text="Volume Cone",bg="yellow", fg="black")
    mylabel.place(x=315, y=125)
    mylabels = Label( text="r : ",bg="yellow", fg="black")
    mylabels.place(x=180, y=155)
    mylabelq = Label( text="h : ",bg="yellow", fg="black")
    mylabelq.place(x=350, y=155)
    a = Entry(width=21)
    a.place(x=200, y=155)
    b = Entry(width=22)
    b.place(x=375, y=155)
    myDel2 = Button( text="CLEAR VOLUME CONE")
    myDel2.place(x=200, y=178)
    my_label2 = Label(height=89,width=259)
    my_label2.place(x=225, y=238)
    myButton23 = Button(width=18, text="calculate", bg="red", fg="white")
    myButton23.place(x=375, y=178)
    wlabel = Label( text="")
        
              
def run():
   show()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Screenshot after clicking show button:

[image]